# Specify submodule revision in PKGBUILD

Tags: arch-linux, git, makepkg, hhvm

I'm trying to install [`hhvm-git`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hhvm-git/) package from AUR and getting an error. There is a bug in one of submodules. This bug is fixed already and I want to specify revision contains that fix for the submodule. How can I do that?

In PKGBUILD I tried to specify revision as suggested in [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VCS_package_guidelines) (line in `source` array):

```
"git+https://github.com/facebook/proxygen#7e37f926d922b55c85537057b57188dea9694c32"
```

Result:

```
  -> Creating working copy of proxygen git repo...
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From /tmp/yaourt-tmp-german/aur-hhvm-git/proxygen
   7e2a49c..3395064  master     -> origin/master
==> ERROR: Unrecognized reference: 7e37f926d922b55c85537057b57188dea9694c32
```

Comment: Don't use yaourt; use makepkg. And specify the commit/revision etc: `source=('project_name::git+http://project_url#commit=345636363')`

Comment: Thank you very much! I have added `commit=` and it works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I specified revision in wrong format. Correct format in my case is:

```
"git+https://github.com/facebook/proxygen#commit=7e37f926d922b55c85537057b57188dea9694c32"
```

From `man PKGBUILD`:

### USING VCS SOURCES

Building a developmental version of a package using sources from a version control system (VCS) is enabled by specifying the source in the form
source=('directory::url#fragment'). Currently makepkg supports the Bazaar, Git, Subversion, and Mercurial version control systems. For other version control systems,
manual cloning of upstream repositories must be done in the prepare() function.

The source URL is divided into three components:

- **directory**
  (optional) Specifies an alternate directory name for makepkg to download the VCS source into.
- **url**
  The URL to the VCS repository. This must include the VCS in the URL protocol for makepkg to recognize this as a VCS source. If the protocol does not include the VCS
  name, it can be added by prefixing the URL with vcs+. For example, using a Git repository over HTTPS would have a source URL in the form: git+https://....
- **fragment**
  (optional) Allows specifying a revision number or branch for makepkg to checkout from the VCS. For example, to checkout a given revision, the source line would have
  the format source=(url#revision=123). The available fragments depends on the VCS being used:

  - **bzr:** revision (see 'bzr help revisionspec' for details)
  - **git:** branch, commit, tag
  - **hg:** branch, revision, tag
  - **svn:** revision

Answer (score 0):

You can edit build files and specify `fragment` option, e.g.:

```bash
pkgdesc='A YANG data modelling language parser and toolkit written (and providing API) in C'
url="https://github.com/CESNET/${pkgname}"
fragment=c035fe6
```

From `man PKGBUILD`

> fragment
> (optional) Allows specifying a revision number or branch for makepkg to checkout from the VCS. A fragment has the form type=value, for example, to checkout a given revision the source line would be
> source=(url#revision=123). The available types depend on the VCS being used:
>
> bzr: revision (see 'bzr help revisionspec' for details)
>
> fossil: branch, commit, tag
>
> git: branch, commit, tag
>
> hg: branch, revision, tag
>
> svn: revision